# The plugin does not work on new tab in gui mode

Tags: vim, vim-plugin

I use flake8-vim plugin. http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4440

If I type:

```
gvim blabla/python_code_file.py
```

I can use command:

```
:PyFlake
```

Then if I open a new type:

```
:tabnew blabla/another_python_code_file.py
```

I can not use that command anymore on that particular tab:

```
:PyFlake
E492: Not an editor command: PyFlake
```

But the command still works in the original tab.
What is happening here?

Comment: Is that file correctly recognized as a python file?

Comment: Well, how do I make sure the new tab is correctly recognized as a python file or not? Looking at the syntax colouring which is the same as the original tab, I guess it is correctly recognized as a python file.

Comment: You can see that with `:set ft`. But what you describe looks like a bug in the plugin to me.

Comment: You are maybe right. It could be a bug in the plugin. I got filetype=python for both tabs. Thank you.